# Uninitialized constant Post in rails console, following tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

So I'm following this tutorial, and I have triple checked that everything I've done up to this point is correct. Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OzDgi0zqJU

At the beginning of the video, he wants me to start the rails console and type "Post.all". I'm getting this error (below) while his terminal displaying a empty array.

```
EIERs-MBP:training eier$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 75415
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.3.0 :001 > Post.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Post
from (irb):1
from /Users/eier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from /Users/eier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/eier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from /Users/eier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /Users/eier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/eier/Documents/Workspace/rails/training/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/eier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/eier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've looked everywhere for answers on what this might be, I don't know if it's because of the rails version I'm using or not. It's a really simple tutorial, so it's really frustrating. We're suppose to create content in the rails console with Post.create(title: "first post", content: "test"), but I'm stuck on the error when typing "Post.all".

Here's the posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 def index

 end
end
```

This is what his file looks as well, and all other files such as index.html.erb and routes we've created. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Do you have the model post, in `app/models/post.rb`

Comment: have you migrated the database?

Comment: @Sravan We haven't created a model yet, I'm sure it's in the next steps of the tutorial. It would be weird if he didn't showed us that and went on to do this, but maybe he did.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss We haven't come this far in the tutorial. We've only set up one route (get '/posts' => 'posts#index'), created a controller (posts_controller.rb) and a view file views/posts/index.html.erb

Comment: I just checked out the tutorial. Strangely enough, it does in fact start with the controller and make use of the model before explicitly going over how to create it. I think that tutorial is more about routes in particular than about rails a whole.

Comment: so, there you are, `Post.alll` says that, you should have a model and it is the data of that model

Comment: Jup! @Sravan, you were right about it. I was just taking his tutorial literally and ignored the fact that you need a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a model `Post` using the command,

`rails generate model Post title:string text:text`

This creates `app/models/post.rb` and a migratiuon file in `db/migrate`

Now, run the migration, if you already have the database.

`rails db:migrate`

Now, the table is created.

Now open `rails console`/`rails c`

`Post.all`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out after @Glyoko noticed that he skipped the model part in the tutorial. I'm still new to rails, so I take every tutorial literally even tho I've learned how to generate a model and migrating a database. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your posts_controller.rb has nothing to do with it. Check that your app/models/post.rb defines

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord # sometimes "< ActiveRecord::Base" instead
end
```

When you type `Post.all`, ruby tries to lookup a class called `Post`–your model–and call the `all` method on it. If it says `uninitialized constant Post` in the error, then your post model must not be defined.

Comment: Ah, I see! Now something is happening, but I got a new error.

2.3.0 :001 > Post.all
  Post Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: posts: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"

Comment: It looks like your tutorial is more about creating routes than about learning rails as a whole. I would recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRyUn7D8zCc if you're trying to learn rails. The first couple videos are about install and fundamentals, but if you want to pick roughly from where you are now, skip to part 4. I would recommend reviewing the basics if you're new to Ruby, however.

Comment: I got it now, thank you for clearing that up for me. I just ran rails generate model post title: content: and migrated the database. Now I'm on track again, thank you!